# Calculating time difference with different base years in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assumme I have the following data:

```
d = {'origin': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'destination': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], 'value': [10, 17, 22, 7, 8, 14, 10, 2, 5, 7, 78, 23] }
data_frame  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data_frame.set_index(['origin', 'destination'], inplace=True)
data_frame
```

What I want to achieve is the following. I want to calculate the time differences w.r.t column `value` for each **origin-destination pair** (given as an index) for two cases.

In the first case, I want the year 2000 as a base. So that the corresponding value will be subtracted from the values in upcoming years (including 2000). Once the year reaches 2003, the base year will become 2003, and it continues to subtract.

If it is a little bit unclear, here is the final dataset I want to achieve

```
d = {'origin': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'destination': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], 'value': [10, 17, 22, 7, 8, 14, 10, 2, 5, 7, 78, 23],  'diff': [0, 7, 12, 0, 1, 7, 0, -8, -5, 0, 71, 16], }
data_frame  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data_frame.set_index(['origin', 'destination'], inplace=True)
data_frame
```

For each origin-destination pair, the difference is calculated having the base year 2000 and then switches to 2003.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Series` for subtracting by replace `value` to missing values if no match `2000,2003` and then forward filling `NaN`s per groups:

```
s = (data_frame['value'].where(data_frame['year'].isin([2000, 2003]))
                        .groupby(level=[0,1])
                        .ffill())
data_frame['diff'] = data_frame['value'].sub(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc(data_frame):
  if data_frame['year'] < 2003:
    x = data_frame['value'] - 10
    return x
  else:
    y = data_frame['value'] - 7
    return y

data_frame['diff'] = data_frame.apply(calc, axis=1)
```